# How to send mail through BPMN 2.0 with Camunda?

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, business-process-management, camunda

I try to send mail with only BPMN 2.0 and not with DelegateTask or a listener.

I tried this :

```
<bpmn2:serviceTask id="ServiceTask_1" name="mailService" camunda:type="mail">
  <bpmn2:extensionElements>
    <camunda:field name="to" stringValue="test@test.com" />
    <camunda:field name="subject" expression="Hello" />
    <camunda:field name="html" expression="Hello" />
   </bpmn2:extensionElements>
</bpmn2:serviceTask>
```

But it fail :

```
Caused by: org.camunda.bpm.engine.ClassLoadingException: Could not load class: org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.MailActivityBehavior
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.util.ReflectUtil.loadClass(ReflectUtil.java:85)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.util.ReflectUtil.instantiate(ReflectUtil.java:147)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/mail/EmailException
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.util.ReflectUtil.loadClass(ReflectUtil.java:65)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException
```

I've also add mail-1.5.0.jar, commons-emails-1.2.jar and commons-logging-1.jar to $CAMUNDA_HOME/server/apache-tomcat-***/lib.

I work with Camunda 7.1.0-Final on Tomcat server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In which `lib` folder did you add the commons-emails-1.2.jar etc?

If you copied them to the `lib` folder in `$CAMUNDA_HOME` (the directory where also the `start-camunda.sh` file exists) then please move them to the `lib` folder of the application server (e.g. `$CAMUNDA_HOME/server/apache-tomcat-7.0.50/lib/`).

Comment: Hi!, sorry to be imprecise, i put in $CAMUNDA_HOME/server/apache-tomcat-version/lib/ folder. But I also tried in $CAMUNDA_HOME/lib, same error.

Comment: Hi, I would suggest to continue this discussion in our [forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/camunda-bpm-users) and would it be possible to provide a minimal failing example project? I'm not able to reproduce your problem with the jars added to the `lib` folder. Thanks